# Show Loading window jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Am trying to display a loading div when an ajax post request send. Tried with these code its not working. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.pagerlink').click(function(event){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#load').show();
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#load').hide();
        },
        $.post(
                "invited-friends",
                { gameid: id },
         function(data) {
               $('#middlefriends').html(data);
          }

        );
    });
});
```

My `html` code

Loading ..

```
     <a id="1" class="pagerlink" >hi</a>
```

Am expecting to display load `div` when an `ajax` post occurs. And hide load `div` after request complete.

Comment: Why `beforeSend` and `complete` are set as part of the `click` event and not the `$.post` call? I'm surprised you didn't get any error messages.

Comment: sorry am new to ajax. Am not getting any results

Comment: Best advice would be to open your console for debugging purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's modified code :-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.pagerlink').click(function(event){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#load').show();
        $.post("invited-friends", { gameid: id }, function(data) {
            $('#load').hide();
            $('#middlefriends').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @Promod Pandey, please help me to write a fail function, then i can hide the #load div there 
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
$('#load').hide();
  })

Comment: @Dibish add ur fail function code after $.post. ex:- $.post("invited-friends", { gameid: id }, function(data) {
            $('#load').hide();
            $('#middlefriends').html(data);
        }) .fail(function() { alert( "error" ); $('#load').hide(); })

Answer (score 2):

You can instead use the [`.ajaxStart`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/) and [`.ajaxStop`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstop/) methods:

```js
var loading = $("#load");
$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function () { loading.show(); },
    ajaxStop : function () { loading.hide(); }
});
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajaxstart.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajaxstop.asp

Comment: i wouldn't use a global ajax for just a specific request , anyway +1

Comment: @A.Wolff This is in conformance with the jQuery documentation. As of 1.8, `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` should only be attached to `document`.

Comment: @JonathanSampson sure but i'm talking about using global ajax method which will be fired for all requests instead of using option for a specific request

Comment: @A.Wolff Ah, I see what you are saying. Lacking specific details about their project, this is generally the approach I take. A general indicator that the page is presently querying the server.

Answer (score 2):

your are doing it wrong. If you are trying to make ajax call then it should be like this

```
$.ajax({
    url:"invited-friends",
    data: { gameid: id },
    type:'POST',
    success:function(data) {
        $('#middlefriends').html(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#load').show();
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#load').hide();
    }
});
```